# SQL - Repeat the last known value until yesterday

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, common-table-expression

I have a table with Date, ID and Value. For some ID, I don't have the value up to yesterday. I need to repeat the last known value for each ID until yesterday where it's NULL.
I've already used a CTE to fill the NULL values between 2 non-NULL values but it doesn't work to fill until yesterday.
The data looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----+-------+
|   Date    | ID  | Value |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| 1/25/2019 | 111 |    50 |
| 1/26/2019 | 111 |   100 |
| 1/27/2019 | 111 |   150 |
| 1/25/2019 | 222 |   500 |
| 1/26/2019 | 222 |  1000 |
| 1/27/2019 | 222 |  1500 |
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

I tried the following code, but got unsuccessful:

```
WITH CAwithnext AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    LEAD("date") OVER (PARTITION BY "id" ORDER BY "date") AS "NextValue"
  FROM "transform_data_1"
  )
SELECT
    c."Date",
    ig."id",
    ig."value"
FROM "calendar_from_2015_to_2025" AS c
JOIN "CAwithnext" AS ig
    ON c."Date" BETWEEN ig."date" AND ISNULL(DATEADD(day,-1,ig."NextValue"),ig."date")
;
```

Here is the expected result:

```
+-----------+-----+-------+
|   Date    | ID  | Value |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| 1/25/2019 | 111 |    50 |
| 1/26/2019 | 111 |   100 |
| 1/27/2019 | 111 |   150 |
| 1/28/2019 | 111 |   150 |
| 1/29/2019 | 111 |   150 |
| 1/30/2019 | 111 |   150 |
| 1/31/2019 | 111 |   150 |
| 1/25/2019 | 222 |   500 |
| 1/26/2019 | 222 |  1000 |
| 1/27/2019 | 222 |  1500 |
| 1/28/2019 | 222 |  1500 |
| 1/29/2019 | 222 |  1500 |
| 1/30/2019 | 222 |  1500 |
| 1/31/2019 | 222 |  1500 |
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the code you've tried so far, please?

Comment: `WITH CAwithnext AS (
  SELECT
   *,
   LEAD("date") OVER (PARTITION BY "id" ORDER BY "date") AS "NextValue"
  FROM "transform_data_1"
  )
SELECT
 c."Date",
 ig."id",
 ig."value"
FROM "calendar_from_2015_to_2025" AS c
JOIN "CAwithnext" AS ig
 ON c."Date" BETWEEN ig."date" AND ISNULL(DATEADD(day,-1,ig."NextValue"),ig."date")
;`

Comment: please edit your question with this query

Comment: @APH, this is the code I used. But this one is working only the fill the missing value between 2 dates. It doesn't work when there is boundaries.

Comment: @JonScott just did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the provided query, when a date is the last available date for an `id`, the next date returned by your `lead` ("NextValue") will be `NULL`.  To fill all the way up to yesterday when "NextValue" is `NULL`, you will need to change your `ISNULL` so that it replaces `NULL` with yesterday's date.

The way you currently have it, when "NextValue" is null it returns the original date instead, which means that for the last value in any `id`'s series, it will only join to your calendar table for the exact `ig.date` value of the original entry.

For example, for `ID = 111`, the last date is 1/27/19, so the "NextValue" for that row would be `NULL`.  If you select from your CTE directly, you should see something like:

```
ID    Date    NextValue
111   1/26/18 1/27/19
111   1/27/19 NULL
```

When you join to your calendar, your `ISNULL` effectively turns your join criteria into `on c.Date between 1/27/19 and isnull(NULL, 1/27/19)`, or `on c.Date between 1/27/19 and 1/27/19`, which is why you're only getting one row back for the last entry.

To resolve, change the last line of your query from:

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(day,-1,ig."NextValue"),ig."date")
```

to

```
ISNULL(DATEADD(day,-1,ig."NextValue"),DATEADD(day,-1,GetDate()))
```

or

```
DATEADD(day,-1,ISNULL(ig."NextValue", GetDate()))
```

(basically, replace `ig.date` with a function that returns the date you want it to populate up to; i.e. yesterday).

Comment: Thank you @APH As I'm fairly new to CTE, could you please insert what would be the modification? I understand your comment but don't really know how to solve it.

Comment: Your CTE looks fine to me - it's actually just the join to the calendar table that needs to be updated.  I'll add some code to the answer.